# После регистрации как правильно хранить данные пользователя

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

Здравствуйте, после регистрации пользователя в приложении, как правильно хранить пароль пользователя?

Если sharedpreferences - это наилучший вариант, можете объяснить почему, и можно ли взломать, и получить данные пользователя?

Comment: AccountManger - удобный и надежный инструмент, посоветовал бы им, ОС берет на себя все задачи шифрования

Answer (score 5, accepted):

данные типа `String` хранятся в `SharedPreferences` в явном виде, практически в текстовом файле. Получить к нему доступ и прочитать эти данные - не очень сложная задача.

Для предотвращения доступа к данным используйте шифрование. Как Core Java (пакеты `crypto` и `security`), так и фреймворк Android (класс `AccountManger` к примеру) предоставляют достаточно инструментов (классов) для надежного шифрования информации.
Способ же сохранения зашифрованных данных отходит на второй план - это может быть БД, преференсы, файл и тп., как удобнее для конкретной задачи (например БД оправдана при хранении нескольких однотипных данных и слишком избыточна для только одного логина-пароля).

Answer (score 4):

Популярное решение - хранить пароль в Базе Данных, и шифровать значение в целях безопасности (выбор БД и способа шифрования зависит от ситуации).
Подумайте о ситуации, в которой вам требуется сохранить малое значение (например флаг состояния). Вероятно, позже вы захотите обратиться к этому значению, когда пользователь будет запускать приложение (например для проверки, запускается приложение первый раз, и нужно ли показать инструкцию). В этом случае стоит использовать SharedPreferences.
SharedPreferences имеет представление ключ-значение, и используется для хранения примитивных типов данных, для последующего использования между пользовательскими сессиями.
Если же вам требуется хранить что-то более объемное, например список пользователей и их паролей, то для этого вам потребуется более сложное представление.